# Does the formula $n^2=(n-1)^2+(n+(n-1))$ have a name or is there a specific proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, algorithms

I've somewhat proven that

$n^2=(n-1)^2+(n+(n-1))$ 
Constraints: $n>0$

*Examples:*

$n=1$: $1^2=(0)^2+(1+0) \to 1=0+1 \to 1=1;$ true 
$n=2$: $2^2=1^2+(2+1) \to 4=1+3 \to 4=4;$ true 
$n=173$: $173^2=172^2+(173+172) \to 29929=29584+345 \to 29929=29929;$ true 
$n=9382$: $9382^2=9381^2+(9382+9381) \to 88021924=88003161+18763$
$\to 88021924=88021924$; true

Does this hold true all the way across all integers?

I'm not $100$% sure I was going to create a software application to test this formula, however everything I've put into it seems to work. I'm more curious if there is a name for this or does it have any place in any area of math?

Comment: You can use Mathematical Induction to prove that

Comment: Here's the proof of formula $n^2=(n-1)^2+(n+(n-1))$ Modifying the RHS, $ n^2+1-2n + n + n - 1 $ Thus RHS reduces to $n^2$ Hence proved

Comment: The identity holds for any numbers, not just positive integers. It is a simple enough formula that it doesn't have a name. Another way to prove it is factor the difference of squares $n^2-(n-1)^2$.

Comment: Awesome thank you for the responses!

Comment: @dxiv "Any numbers" is too wide term. It may depend on the axioms of a specific number system. :)

Comment: @user The identity holds in any commutative ring, which covers most of what's casually called "numbers". My comment was meant to stay on the casual side in the context here.

Comment: @dxiv I don't argue that it holds for most number systems. It is really hard to construct a system with a reasonable definitions of addition and multiplication where this does not hold.

Comment: Using induction here is like shooting rockets on ants.

Answer (score 1):

we can expand the right hand side to see whether it equals the left hand side of our equation.

$$ LHS=n^2$$
$$ RHS=(n-1)^2+n+(n-1)$$
accordingly,
$RHS=n^2-2n+1+2n-1=n^2$

Therefore, $$LHS=RHS=n^2  $$

Thus,we can say that this equation can be proved true for all integers,and it even works for zero